# Transferring files to a USB attached drive

Tags: networking, usb, ssh, netatalk

I did a quick search and found someone who had a similar issue to this but was ahead of me so I'm not sure how to set this up?
I have my pi connected to my router with a 4 bay nas drive connected to the pi via USB. When I turn on the pi and type `startx` I have to add the drives manually each time, which is fine if I keep the pi running 24/7. I have installed netatalk and the home directory shows up on my shared network, but I can't seem to access the media folder. I know I'm supposed to type: 
`sudo nano /etc/netatalk/AppleVolumes.default`
and edit the drive I want to mount but I'm not sure what aprt to edit and when I do change a line down at the bottom which relates to home directory I can no longer connect to the pi?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you trying to connect to or from the Pi? Tell us WHAT YOU DO to " add the drives". `AppleVolumes.default` controls which directories the Pi exposes.

Comment: I apologize. I am trying to connect from a Mac to the Pi with the drives attached to it. I am trying to transfer files from my Mac to the usb drive rather than the pi itself.  When I "add them manually" what I mean is File Manager pops up and asks me what to do with these drives it has found connected to the Pi. I then click ok to make them attach I assume.  The media folder is where my external drives are located.  Hopefully this is a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking 2 questions:-
1. How to automount network drives
2. How to connect to a mounted drive on th Pi using netatalk.

A suggestion for the 2nd is to add lines at the end of `/etc/netatalk/AppleVolumes.default`. Mine contains the line `/etc           "$hRoot"` which lets Appletalk mount the directory `/etc` as "$hRoot" where the $h is replaced by the Pi Hostname (default `raspberrypi`). You could use `/media/MountPoint` for each drive or just `/media` for all mounted volumes.

```
# The line below sets some DEFAULT, starting with Netatalk 2.1.

:DEFAULT: options:upriv,usedots

# By default all users have access to their home directories.
~/          $hHome

:PIROOT: options:upriv,usedots,ro
/etc            "$hRoot"
# End of File
```

I cannot give a definitive answer for the 1st, as I don't do this, but you normally would add an entry to `/etc/fstab`. If you run `mount` after you have manually mounted a drive this will give an idea of the settings. Post a new question about this if you need further help.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I will try this out. I am not so concerned over #1. It was more to do with the second question.